# what is a dispatcher

Tags: c#, multithreading

can anyone please explain the concept of dispatcher, is it one dispatcher per thread or anything else

Comment: Yuo want to know about OS concept, or something specific (like event dispatcher in .Net? Because you tagged question in C#

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're asking in reference to c#, [a dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx)...

> ...maintains a prioritized queue of work items for a specific thread.
>
> When a Dispatcher is created on a thread, it becomes the only Dispatcher that can be associated with the thread, even if the Dispatcher is shut down.

..so yes, one per thread.

Comment: i get a dispatcher property for a button "btnTest.Dispatcher" what does this mean

Comment: it means the button is derived from a `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject`. Look at the Inheritance heirarchy here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms609089%28v=VS.85%29.aspx